# Python multiprocessing pool sometimes impossible to terminate

Tags: python, kubernetes, multiprocessing

I recently ran in a problem, that is driving me crazy.
I am not allowed to share real code, but since it is a non-deterministic rare problem that probbably arises from a special architecture constellation, that maybe would not even help at all.

I am running a kubernetes cluster in GCP. On this cluster I run python code in a docker container. These python jobs use the standard library's Processing Pools (multiprocessing.Pool) to parallelize model training and predicting tasks over some parallelization dimension.

This setup has been working for quite a while but most recently sometimes one of the pods get stuck and won't terminate (maybe every hundredth pod).

A devops colleague told me, that google released an updated kubernetes version as default, so that would be my best guess, what could possibly be causing this problems.

I turned on debugging on multiprocessing module level, so I know that the worker handler does not send the sentinel to the task handler, but I really don't know why!

log output in case the termination stucks:

2022-04-28 12:05:20,989 DEBUG util - debug: terminating pool
2022-04-28 12:05:20,989 DEBUG util - debug: finalizing pool
2022-04-28 12:05:20,992 DEBUG util - debug: helping task handler/workers to finish
2022-04-28 12:05:20,992 DEBUG util - debug: removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished

log output in case everything works well:

2022-04-28 12:05:20,989 DEBUG util - debug: terminating pool
2022-04-28 12:05:20,989 DEBUG util - debug: finalizing pool
2022-04-28 12:05:20,992 DEBUG util - debug: helping task handler/workers to finish
2022-04-28 12:05:20,992 DEBUG util - debug: removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
2022-04-28 12:05:20,993 DEBUG util - debug: worker handler exiting
2022-04-28 12:05:20,993 DEBUG util - debug: task handler got sentinel
2022-04-28 12:05:20,994 DEBUG util - debug: task handler sending sentinel to result handler
2022-04-28 12:05:20,994 DEBUG util - debug: task handler sending sentinel to workers
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,994 DEBUG util - debug: worker got sentinel -- exiting
2022-04-28 12:05:20,994 DEBUG util - debug: result handler got sentinel
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker exiting after 5 tasks
Process(142) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker got sentinel -- exiting
Process(134) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker got sentinel -- exiting
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 INFO util - info: process shutting down
Process(150) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker got sentinel -- exiting
Process(142) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker exiting after 5 tasks
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Process(150) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker exiting after 5 tasks
Process(134) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker exiting after 5 tasks
2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: task handler exiting
Process(150) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 INFO util - info: process shutting down
Process(142) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 INFO util - info: process shutting down
Process(134) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 INFO util - info: process shutting down
Process(142) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Process(150) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: DECREF '7fd260be86a0'
Process(134) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Process(142) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: DECREF '7fd260be86a0'
Process(150) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: DECREF '7fd260be86a0'
Process(158) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker got sentinel -- exiting
Process(166) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker got sentinel -- exiting
Process(134) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: DECREF '7fd260be86a0'
Process(158) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker exiting after 5 tasks
Process(166) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: worker exiting after 5 tasks
Process(158) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 INFO util - info: process shutting down
Process(166) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 INFO util - info: process shutting down
Process(158) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Process(166) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
Process(158) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: DECREF '7fd260be86a0'
Process(166) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: DECREF '7fd260be86a0'
2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: ensuring that outqueue is not full
2022-04-28 12:05:20,995 DEBUG util - debug: joining worker handler
2022-04-28 12:05:20,997 DEBUG util - debug: result handler exiting: len(cache)=0, thread._state=TERMINATE
2022-04-28 12:05:20,997 DEBUG util - debug: terminating workers
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,998 DEBUG util - debug: running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
Process(126) - 2022-04-28 12:05:20,998 INFO util - info: process exiting with exitcode 0
2022-04-28 12:05:20,999 DEBUG util - debug: joining task handler
2022-04-28 12:05:20,999 DEBUG util - debug: joining result handler
2022-04-28 12:05:20,999 DEBUG util - debug: joining pool workers
2022-04-28 12:05:20,999 DEBUG util - debug: cleaning up worker 126
2022-04-28 12:05:21,019 DEBUG util - debug: cleaning up worker 134
2022-04-28 12:05:21,021 DEBUG util - debug: cleaning up worker 150
2022-04-28 12:05:21,022 DEBUG util - debug: cleaning up worker 158
2022-04-28 12:05:21,028 DEEPINFO aiff_logging - deepinfo: Processing pool terminated.
2022-04-28 12:05:21,028 INFO threading - await_queue_empty: Waiting for write queue to be empty...
2022-04-28 12:05:21,028 DEBUG util - debug: thread 'MainThread' does not own a connection
2022-04-28 12:05:21,028 DEBUG util - debug: making connection to manager

sample code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np


def some_function():
    data = np.random.random((1000, 10))
    m = LinearRegression()
    m.fit(data[:, 0:10], data[:, -1])
    return m.predict(data[:, 0:10])

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    results = []

    for _ in range(100):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(func=some_function))

    preds = [res.get() for res in results]
    pool.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have also been trying to close and join the pool istead of termination which also does not work. I have been uying python 3.8 and recently tried 3.9 which both do not work.

I would be really thankful for any piece of advise!

Comment: I believe it happens regularly when "some_function" fails, even in just one thread. You should put a timeout:
`pool.map_async(some_function).get(timeout_pool)`
This at least provides a terminaion and a bit of traceback (not much, admittedly)

Comment: I am pretty sure, the single calls of "some_function" do not fail. At least the logging inside of theses function suggest that.

Comment: Even if it's not deterministic, can you still provide a [mre] of *some* code that fails? Do you use `res.get` or `res.get()`? Since you assume that the kubernetes version is to blame, which kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: k8s version is v1.20.15-gke.3400.

I expanded the example code to some runnable dummy code. You are right: I call the function and do not use res.get (also see example code).